# How can i associate an IBAction event with an image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, ios4

I have a application which contains a moving image and i want to animate the image using a my custom animation.

**How can i associate an IBAction event with the image?**

**How can i detect the coordinates on screen where the user touched the image?**

Please Give Your Suggestions.

Thanks in advance and Your Suggestions are Most Welcome.

Comment: "How can i associate an IBAction event with the image?"--> cant understand can u explain more what you need.

Comment: we have a bouncing ball application where on the user touch we want to change the direction of the ball and the ball is an image. So i want that if i touch the image it should change its directionand hence i want an IBAction event to associate with it. I m a newbee please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this way:

first define the rect where you image will be:

```
touchRect=CGRectMake(screen.width/2-screen.width/8, 0, screen.width/4, screen.height/5);
```

then with touchesEnded method you can define what you want to do when you touch over that zone:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        CGPoint targetPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(touchRect,  targetPoint)){
            //YOUR CODE HERE
        }
}
```

Comment: touchRect=CGRectMake(screen.width/2-screen.width/8, 0, screen.width/4, screen.height/5); 

What is this frame about? i am not very clear about that. please do explain as i m still a newbee.

Comment: how to associate touchesEnded event with imageview in IB? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, its just an example  GRectMake(x position, y position, x size, y size) just create a Rect. Its like creating an invisible square in any position you want so you can check if is there something inside it in your screen

Comment: its not neccesary to add an IBAction here, if you implement touchesEnded whenever you touch your screen it will be called

Comment: in your case you can make a rect with your bouncing ball every time you touch the screen and check if you are touching wherever the ball is.

Comment: What is CCDirector?. I am getting the error: "CCDirector undeclared"

Comment: sorry that is from cocos2d you have to use :                           -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { //Get all the touches.
NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

//Number of touches on the screen

//Get the first touch.
UITouch *touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];            CGPoint targetPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
} and work around that

Comment: In "locationInView:self" i m getting an error stating : Incompatible Objective-C types "struct <MyViewName> *" expected "struct UIView *" What needs to be done?

Answer (score 3):

You could use custom UIButtons with your image. All the touch handling code is already builtin.

---

Edit: UIGestureRecognizer also work on UIImageViews:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]] autorelease];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)] autorelease];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: we have a bouncing ball application where on the user touch we want to change the direction of the ball and the ball is an image. So i  m confused that if i use a button as you said then how will i get it to move as the ball moves.

Comment: the exact same way you would move the UIImageView. Both are UIViews so there should be no difference. But to be honest, for moving objects I would not use the button approach. That just doesn't feel good.    Please see my edit int the answer.