# How can I make an action for a picture?

Tags: xcode4

In my program, I want the users could touch a picture so that an action will be activated. However, the function IBAction cannot allow me to connect it with the picture. Is there any method that can help me to trigger a function when the users touch the picture? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate the User Interaction for that picture, and then detect taps on it and trigger the action based on them.
But the simplest solution would be to just put a button behind it, and connect the IBAction to that button. That's what we do in such cases.

Comment: sorry, could you describe the method of activating the User Interaction for that picture in detail, Thank you so much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922449/how-can-i-associate-an-ibaction-event-with-an-image this link should get you started. The method of activation is very simple. You select the imageView and then check the User Interaction Enabled field in the Attributes Inspector of xcode. A detailed answer would be difficult for me at the moment, I'm not that good with obj-c neither. It depends on how you are planning to use the image. Will it be static, in just one place, will it cover the whole screen, will it move around and so on. If you need further assistence, I'll try to help