# IOS segue is not working when clicking on an Image

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a view with an Image View, when the user clicks on it, I want to load the image inside it in a separate view.

This is my segue:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Player Information"]){
        if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[PlayerViewController class]]){
            PlayerViewController *playerViewController = (PlayerViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
            [playerViewController setPlayer:[self.team.players objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row]];
        }
    }else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Image"]) {
        if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ImageViewerViewController class]]){
            ImageViewerViewController *imageViewerViewController = (ImageViewerViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
            [imageViewerViewController setImageName:@"France.jpg"];
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing happens when clicking on the image view though the segue has the correct identifier.

Please check the below screenshot
[image]

Could you help me please?

I appreciate your time and efforts.

Regards,

Comment: What trigers your segue? Is it a UIButton?

Comment: Have you added performSegueWithIdentifier: anywhere?

Comment: Note that `UIImageView`'s default `userInteractionEnabled` property is (unlike its super `UIView`'s) set to `NO`. Have you set it to `YES`?

Comment: Hi guys, I appreciate your efforts. I will be available after 2 hours.

Comment: @PanayotPanayotov no there is no UIButton

Comment: @MrH no I haven't. What is that message for please?

Comment: @Alladinian no I haven't how could I do that please?

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments but I have noticed that each one of you gave a different answer, should I apply these three answers together please?

Comment: Just select your imageView and check the appropriate box in the inspector. Or programmatically like `myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: @Alladinian I'll try that but please why is this strange behavior? In the table view, everything I needed to navigate to a new ViewController is dragging a segue from the cell and sending the `prepareForSegue` message. Why it is different in the ImageView ?

Comment: @CarolSmith Unlike other `UIViews` (like buttons, cells etc) `UIImageView` (and also `UILabel`) are most often used for just presenting information, so their default `userInteractionEnabled` value is set to `NO`

Comment: @Alladinian I selected that property from inspector, but unfortunately nothing has changed. I mean when clicking on the image, nothing happens.

Comment: ok we'll need some more info. Just tried on a fresh project and apparently IB doesn't let you create a segue directly from an image. An easy solution would be to have a `UIButton` instead and set _its_ image instead of just an imageView directly. After that you can create your segue as usual.

Comment: @Alladinian First, I appreciate your efforts with me. Second, there could be another solution than replacing it with a button. I would prefer a coding solution if that is possible too. What do you think?

Comment: @CarolSmith No worries, that's what SO is all about :) Of course is possible to do it directly from an image (although I think it is way easier to do it with a button), but in any way here is a [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643115/how-can-i-make-an-action-for-a-picture) to get you started

Comment: @Alladinian something interesting...The answer of your suggested question states to add a button to behind the image. so technically, I don't need to change the imageview . I will try that

Comment: @Alladinian I am sorry for keep asking but I am new to IOS developing (as you already noticed). Now I've added a new UIButton and connected it to an action. what should I do to fire the new ViewController? and should I remove the already exited segue? or maybe I need to make a segue from this UIButton without the action? Many thanks dear

Comment: @CarolSmith No worries, as I said that's the point of this website. Just delete your old segue, `ctrl`+drag from your button to your destination controller, choose 'push', set the segue identifier to `Show Image` and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Alladinian Many thanks for your efforts with me. It works. Please write an answer to accept it. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is possible to perform a segue from a `UIImageView` (although not directly from IB) in my opinion is much simpler to just replace it with a `UIButton` and set *its* image instead.

Then, based on your posted code, you could just remove your old segue, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>drag</kbd> from the button to your destination controller, choose 'push' and then set the segue identifier to `Show Image`.

---

It should be noted here that `UIImageView` (unlike its ancestor `UIView`) has its `userInteractionEnabled` property set to `NO` by default ([more about it here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimageview_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889-CH3-SW13)). So if you choose to handle any events directly from the `UIImageView` make sure that you switch it to `YES` ([here is a similar answer regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643115/how-can-i-make-an-action-for-a-picture)).

Comment: Dear, could you check my new question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061743/ios-user-experience-for-allowing-user-to-change-map-type I appreciate your time and efforts